# Waiting for user input, but can't get right userinput

Tags: java, database, hibernate

So in my program the user will have to input some data to add to a database. The only problem is that this data is never send to the database.

```
if(menuReturn==2){
            System.out.println("\n\n");
            System.out.println("Geef de film naam: ");
            data=reader.next();
            Movies newmovie= new Movies();
            newmovie.setMovie_name(data);
            session.save(newmovie);
            System.out.println("Wat wilt u doen?:\n1) Check filmlijst\n2)Voeg film toe\n3)Check klantenlijst\n4)Voeg klant toe\n5)Check uitstaande lijst\n6)Voeg Rental toe\n7)Film binnengebracht\n8)Print alle Rentals\n9)Exit");
            menuReturn=reader.nextInt();
        }
```

I use this for my userinput but it will never add a name to my database

Comment: **Commit** the transaction.

Comment: Do you see the syso messages?

Comment: Is this getting printed? :System.out.println("Wat wilt u doen?:\n1) Check filmlijst\n2)Voeg film toe\n3)Check klantenlijst\n4)Voeg klant toe\n5)Check uitstaande lijst\n6)Voeg Rental toe\n7)Film binnengebracht\n8)Print alle Rentals\n9)Exit");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to commit your transaction  or have to explicitly `flush` your data.

Safest is the wrapping [with Transaction](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html).

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
 Movies newmovie= new Movies();
 newmovie.setMovie_name(data);
session.save(newmovie);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: If I do this it will end my application that is running, and it will still nog save my data to the database

Answer (score 0):

Specific issue can't found by showing this much of code but you should **Commit** transaction after save method.

Comment: But if I commit will my connection not be closed?

Comment: No connection will be still open, commit will instruct hibernate to make data persistent, connection will close when you call session.close() or object removed from the memory.

Comment: So I changed my code with to commit right after the save. But when it commits it will never sned the data to the database, and it will stop my application